# Python checking type of list elements

Tags: python, abc

I'm trying use ABC and...
Checking type of single parameter is quite straithforward:

```
def spam_method(param):
  if not isinstance(param, SpamInterface):
    raise TypeError
```

It looks good. In first line of method definition is mentioned what type I require. But what about passing lists? I'm doing it in this way:

```
def many_spams(list_param):
  if list_param and not isinstance(list_param[0], SpamInterface):
    raise TypeError
```

But I'm not exactly satisfied with that. Any more elegant way? How would you do it?

Comment: You want to check that no instances inside `list_param` are of `SpamInterface`?

Comment: It really depends on the constraints you're looking for. Is checking the first element sufficient? Remember that Python lists can contain objects of any type, so you may want to check the type of all elements. Or check them as you (presumably) iterate the list. Right now this is fairly opinion-based.

Comment: If you want to confirm that every element in the list is a certain type you will need to iterate through the whole list in some way, which will always be O(n).

Comment: Actually I don't want to check exactly every element of the list. It is rather about expressing types the metod excepts. My projects grows and I have trouble controlling dependencies between modules.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to check that *every object in `list_param` are of type `SpamInterface`*. If that is the case, there are 2 different ways to check. First, the lazy way in which we use the `all()` function:

```
def many_spams(list_param):
    if not all(isinstance(p, SpamInterface) for p in list_param):
        raise TypeError('Not all objects are of type SpamInterface')
```

This method is short, but it will not tell you which element in the list failed the test. The second method offers a little more details:

```
def many_spams(list_param):
    for index, param in enumerate(list_param):
        if not isinstance(param, SpamInterface):
            raise TypeError('Parameter at index {} is not of type SpamInterface: {}'.format(index, param))
```

This method will throw an exception at the first element that is not of type `SpamInterface`.